# Upsert only if existing record is older than N days

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to upsert a record in a way that it checks if the existing record is older than N days. If it is, then create a new record, else just updated the existing one

Comment: With a trigger probably.

Comment: If possible i'd like to avoid the usage of such, and just stick with a query

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including the primary key and index definitions), some sample data and the expected result based on that sample data. [_Formatted_](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: please also specify the version of postgresql being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer pure SQL solution, then try the below way.
Sample data:

```
create table abcd(
  id serial,
  name varchar(100),
  value int,
  created date
 );

 insert into abcd( name, value, created) values
 ( 'name 1', 10, current_date - interval '10' day),
 (  'name 2', 55, current_date - interval '120' day);

 ;

 select * from abcd;

id |name   |value |created    |
---|-------|------|-----------|
1  |name 1 |10    |2016-12-14 |
2  |name 2 |55    |2016-08-26 |
```

---

The query:

```
 with  records  as (
    select *,
           case when created >= current_date - interval '10' day
                then 'UPDATE' else 'INSERT' end as what_to_do
    from abcd
 ),
 up_date as (
    update abcd set value = 1000
    where id in (select id from records where what_to_do = 'UPDATE')
    returning id
 ),
 in_sert as (
    insert into abcd( name, value, created)
    select name, 1000, current_date
    from records where what_to_do = 'INSERT'
    returning id
 )
 select *  from up_date 
 union all
 select *  from in_sert
 ;

select * from abcd; 
id |name   |value |created    |
---|-------|------|-----------|
2  |name 2 |55    |2016-08-26 |
1  |name 1 |1000  |2016-12-14 |
3  |name 2 |1000  |2016-12-24 |
```